# Create thumbnails (screenshots) of websites from list of URLs

Tags: gratis, images, image-processing, screenshot, scraping

I'm looking for software that will take my list of URLs and for each one create a thumbnail of the site.

It must:

- Be free software I can run on Windows or Debian Linux
- Create thumbnails of equal size

Bonus points if:

- I can specify thumbnail file name per URL in my URL list
- I can set thumbnail dimensions (width / height)
- Renders Flash correctly.